# Is the NLT interpretation/translation of Psalm 51:6 accurate?

Tags: psalms, nt-use-of-hebrew-bible, 2-timothy

> [Psa 51:6 NLT] (6) But you desire honesty from the womb, teaching me wisdom even there.

Other translations render more literally as "hidden part" instead of "womb".

I'm wondering if this might be an allusion to the Psalm:

> [2Ti 3:13-17 KJV] (13) But evil men and seducers shall wax worse and worse, deceiving, and being deceived. (14) But continue thou in the things which thou hast learned and hast been assured of, **knowing of whom thou hast learned them; (15) And that from a child thou hast known the holy scriptures**, which are able to make thee wise unto salvation through faith which is in Christ Jesus. (16) **All scripture is given by inspiration of God**, and is profitable for doctrine, for reproof, for correction, for instruction in righteousness: (17) That the man of God may be perfect, throughly furnished unto all good works.

If so, then the one who taught Timothy is God ("they shall all be taught of God") and he learned them as an unborn child by his receiving the divine breath. In which case Paul's reference to "God-breathed" may mean "by direct revelation". And of course Timothy need not be embarassed by his lack of human training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not talking about loving wisdom from the womb, but:

> **Psalm 51:6 (Doauy-Rheims)** For behold thou hast loved truth: the uncertain and hidden things of thy wisdom thou hast made manifest to me.

The Hebrew reads:

> הן אמת הפצת בטהות ובסתם הכמה תודיעני

Which I would render:

> Behold thou delightest in truth: thou makest me learned in  the hidden and the concealed things of wisdom.

The first part is easy: הן אמת הפצת (*Hinn ameth haphsah*): "Behold you delight in truth." The second part, בטהות ובסתם ("in [the] hidden/obscure and in [the] closed up things"). And of course הכמה (*hokhmah*) means "wisdom." Then the verb תודיעני is a second person verb *hifil* form of to know  meaning "You cause *me* to know" ("me" denoted by the affixed Yod—Todia'an*i*).

The interpretation of 2 Timothy 3, however, is bewildering, since Paul says Scriptures being as they are breathed by God are thus profitable for *the man* of God in his process of *perfection*, and *righteousness* (Isaiah 7:16), and able to *make one wise with regard to matters of salvation*, all things that are meaningless to babies: babies can't read the Scriptures, nor has any been known to have have an inborn knowledge of them before reading them.

Comment: I notice that the word translated "childhood" generally refers to an unborn child or a newborn:  https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G1025&t=NLT   Also: [Luk 1:44 NLT] (44) When I heard your greeting, the baby in my womb jumped for joy.  Perhaps Lois read to young Timmy?

Comment: Also, [Heb 8:10-11 NLT] (10) But this is the new covenant I will make with the people of Israel on that day, says the LORD: I will put my laws in their minds, and I will write them on their hearts. I will be their God, and they will be my people. (11) And they will not need to teach their neighbors, nor will they need to teach their relatives, saying, 'You should know the LORD.' For everyone, from the least to the greatest, will know me already.

Comment: Timmy in the tummy?

Comment: [Jhn 7:15 KJV] (15) And the Jews marvelled, saying, How knoweth this man letters, having never learned?  [Act 4:13 KJV] (13) Now when they saw the boldness of Peter and John, and perceived that they were unlearned and ignorant men, they marvelled; and they took knowledge of them, that they had been with Jesus.   I'm going to ask a follow-up question.

Comment: Actually, the DRB reading seems to work better and seems to be what Brenton Septuagint has:  51:6 For, behold, thou lovest truth: thou hast manifested to me the secret and hidden things of thy wisdom.  So that is probably what Paul was looking at.